# How do I remove all undefs from array?

Tags: arrays, perl, undef

While reading from a configuration file in Perl there might be cases when a line is invalid and it does not need to get added to my array of valid lines. Since I'm using a for loop here, even the invalid lines create an undef entry. How can I remove all them afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: if you're creating the config file use a module like Config::Simple.  If you're reading the content of a pre-existing config file into an array why are you pushing invalid entries into your array instead of skipping them?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
@array = grep defined, @array;
```

Comment: simple and great solution

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you for this simple solution.

Comment: Interesting, I am seeing `defined(@array) is deprecated at /path/to/script.pl line X.` using perl 5.10.1 (yes I realize the year is 2021, but I gotta work with what I got)

Comment: Should have added this immediately, but

`@array = grep {defined} @array;` 

works for my particular flavor of Perl.