# Perl: use of uninitialized variable in nested foreach

Tags: regex, perl

Trying to check an array of strings against an array of regex 's.

Throws:

'Use of uninitialized value in $string in pattern match (m//) at myscript line '

If I take out the if statement, it still gives warning but prints each
element in the @string_list

```
foreach my $expr (@expr_list) {
   foreach my $string (@string_list) {
     if ($string =~ $expr) {
        print $string,"\n"
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Which line # is in the error message?

Comment: Add the value of `@expr_list` and `@string_list` to the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122977/how-do-i-remove-all-undefs-from-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means one of the elements of `@string_list` is `undef`.